# How do I make a Rock Candy Xbox 360 controller vibrate on Windows 10 64-bit?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, windows-10

I'm trying to enable force feedback on a Rock Candy Xbox 360 controller on my computer. My computer runs 64-bit Windows 10.

I've looked everywhere, but everything I get looks like malware while the rest looks like it works for Windows 7 or 8.

How do I get this type of controller to vibrate on games for the PC?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a software problem, your controller doesn't have vibration motors. [From the manufacturer's support page:](https://support.pdp.com/hc/en-us/articles/204609088-Why-doesn-t-my-controller-vibrate-)

> **Why doesn't my controller vibrate?**
>
> There are no vibration motors in the Rock Candy Controllers.